# Convert collection of T into collection of QVariant in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, templates, collections

In Qt, how can I convert a typed collection of objects such as a `QList<T>` into a `QList<QVariant>`? I suppose I could construct a new list and copy the elements over, converting each to a `QVariant` along the way, but is there a shortcut?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the Qt IRC chat room. It was staring me right in the face.

```
QList<MyClass> source = ...;
QVariant variant = QVariant::fromValue(source);
```

The variant here is a `QList<QVariant>`.

Comment: In Qt 4.6 MinGW the QVariant contains a `QList<MyClass>`. I believe that only when you call `value<QList<QVariant> >` it will do a conversion.